# jQuery- serializeArray() with same name inputs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with rows of products to added to sql. User can add new rows. I'm trying to serialize it and post using .ajax.
Serialize code:

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
var values = {};
$("#results").empty();
$.each(fields, function(i, field){
     values[field.name] = field.value;               
});
```

But the problem is that my inputs have the same name eg.:

```
<td width="3%"><input type="text" size="5" name="products[][prod_qnt]" value="1"/></td>
```

in the next row is the same cell and serializeArray() passing only first row. Why?

Comment: Why are you coping the data to `values`? It will overwrite form values with the same name. Just pass `fields` to the Ajax method (whichever you use).

Comment: Where do you do the jQuery POST?

Comment: Why do you have the `$.each()` loop at all? You can just pass `fields` to the AJAX call. It does have all the data, it's just that they all have the same `field.name` so you keep writing data to the same index.

Comment: I removed $.each() and pass only fields and everything is ok now. I don't know why i'm using this function... Thanks alot.